# Несовместимость скриптов

Tags: php, css

Подключаю в модальном окне (на css и html) <?php include(""); ?> и сайт становиться пустым, а когда убираю php из модального окна, все нормально.
Пробывал сам скрипт вставить в модальное окно, но все равно. Вообще ни какие php функции подключаю если, то не отображает страницы.

```
<style>
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: default;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
.overlay:target {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.popup {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 30%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    top: 25%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-17%, -17%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-17%, -17%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-17%, -17%);
    -o-transform: translate(-17%, -17%);
    transform: translate(-17%, -17%);

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;

    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}
.overlay:target+.popup {
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.close {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: -15px;
    width: 30px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -ms-border-radius: 15px;
    -o-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.close:before {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    content: "X";
    font-size: 24px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(64, 128, 128, 0.8);
}
.popup p, .popup div {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
</style>
<title>Настройки | GamesFB</title>

<?php include("blocks/header-auth.php"); ?>  //Подключение шапки

<a href="#x" class="overlay" id="login"></a> //модальное окно
        <div class="popup">
<?php include("verefication/changes-pass.php"); ?> //подключение в модальное окно
        <a class="close"title="Закрыть" href="#close"></a>
        </div>
```

**changes-pass.php** - обработчик

```
<?php
$login = $_POST["login"];
$newslogin = $_POST["newslogin"];

if($_POST['newslogin']!=null){
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `login` = $newslogin WHERE `login` = $login") or die("Запрос с ошибкой ".mysql_error());;
}else{
exit("Ошибка. Вы не ввели свой логин.");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> сайт становиться

сайт **становится**

> Подключаю в модальном окне (на css и html) <?php include(""); ?> и сайт становиться пустым

Скажите, а как, по-вашему, должна отработать директива

```
<?php include(""); ?>
```

? Вы запрашиваете файл без имени, PHP стреляет ошибкой, скрипт завершает работу.

Comment: Нет, у меня с именем. 

`
<?php include("verefication/changes-pass.php"); ?> //подключение в модальное окно
`

Comment: @cnofss, а он точно существует по этому **относительному пути**?

Comment: Да, конечно

Comment: @cnofss, включите отображение ошибок, тогда узнаете, почему у вас сайт стоновится "пустым"...